# What is the position of a delegate class of a UITableView in mvc?

Tags: ios, uitableview, design-patterns

I have a delegate class which separated from UIViewController for UITableView.
And I'm wondering the class is a model, a view or a controller?

Comment: It's probably a "logic controller" https://www.swiftbysundell.com/posts/logic-controllers-in-swift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what your class does, but in all probability it should be considered part of your Controller architecture, because it is part of the mechanism that mediates between the model (the underlying data) and the view (the table view).

Another way to consider the matter is: Is this class portable to any old project, or does it do work that it pretty much unique to the functionality of this one app? If the latter, it is probably Controller.

Having said all that, I would suggest that it might be better to drop this insistence of classifying everything as model, view, or controller. Like the childhood game of "animal, vegetable, or mineral", it takes a narrow and highly simplified view of the world. There is a lot more to life than this. To understand the place of a delegate class in the architecture of an object-oriented program, you might do better to study, say, *Design Patterns* (the well-known classic book by the "Gang of Four", Gamma, Helms, Johnson, and Vlissides).

Answer (score 0):

`UITableView` uses two objects that behave like delegates - `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource`. Neither of them is on any specific side, though - they perform the function of the "glue" connecting the three together.

For example, `UITableViewDataSource` is part of the model because it knows the structure of your custom data. It is also part of the view, because it configures cell objects displayed by `UITableView`. Finally, it is part of the controller, because it makes modifications in response to end-user's actions on the view.

`UITableViewDelegate` does not have its own "letter" ini MVC, because it is part of the *View Controller* - a layer that controls presentation of data, without being that representation (i.e. it is *not* a view). View controller is to *View* what *Controller* is to *Model*, because it has the logic that handles various aspects of presenting the data without having contact with the data itself.